# Run JConsole from server over SSH

Tags: java, ssh, jconsole

I deployed a Java app to server and need to run Jconsole for profiling. I connected to server over SSH and run jconsole, however I got an error

```
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
```

How can I run JConsole over SSH on my client machine?

Comment: what OS is running on your client machine ?

Answer (score 2):

when connection to the server, enable X forwarding with `ssh -X $servername`

Comment: This presupposes an X server on the client machine; it's possible OP doesn't have one running or even know what that is.